# uiwebview default player fullscreen mode

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiwebview, fullscreen

when a youtube video embedded in a uiwebview is played in full screen mode, the device doesnt detect orientation change ...Is there a way to resolve this ??

If not, is there an alternative way to get notification when the default webview media player exits fullscreen mode ??

Thanks in advance.